# Change Display Managers Without Input

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm, slim

so I am working on a project which will be a Lubuntu install without touching anything during the install process (except after a few seconds of quick input), and I want to uninstall lightdm and install SLiM (thanks to reasons of default session, lighterweight, and more) - however I do not want to have to run    `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`    unless I can do so in a way that does not require input. I tried to be clever and run    `sudo apt-get remove lightdm`    and then    `sudo apt-get install slim`    and I thought that would work. But when I booted into Lubuntu, it only showed wmaker, blackbox, and icewm as options for sessions. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You can try preseeding a debconf selection and then use a non-interactive frontend for `dpkg-reconfigure`. First find the correct key for preseeding:

```
$ debconf-get-selections | grep lightdm
# Choices: gdm, lightdm
gdm     shared/default-x-display-manager        select  lightdm
lightdm shared/default-x-display-manager        select  lightdm
```

So set, perhaps:

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<EOF
slim    shared/default-x-display-manager        select  slim
lightdm shared/default-x-display-manager        select  slim
EOF
```

Then either of, depending on whether you already have `slim` installed:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install slim
```

Comment: Lol. I don't have enough rep to upvote. Sorry. I will check this out, may work well sense we are already using preseeding. Do you think this will solve the issue I'm having though? Because another command I ran was sudo apt-get remove apt-get install lxdeand lubuntu-desktop for compatibility reasons with SLiM

Comment: To no prevail. Funny enough, I went into bash (to test this out) after running everything, and reinstalled lightdm, and strange enough when I did 'debconf-get-selections | grep lightdm' it showed 'select slim' already; making me think that my cheapness of my uninstalling lightdm first worked. Now why does it not show xsessions as sessions and only shows wmaker, blackbox, and icewm...

Comment: Confirmed not updating xession. Tried installing another DE and it did not show up in SLiM